# EntityFramework 7 with Azure Table Storage provider code samples

Tags: azure-table-storage, entity-framework-core

Looking for some code samples of EF7 with Azure Table Storage provider

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Azure Table Storage provider was a prototype and will not be supported by EF Core until after 1.0. 
See https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/1142

Also note, the ATS provider was [removed](https://github.com/aspnet/entityframework/commit/f55ff77848720dc60cb4ae18ffdc0c5d9aa03987) from the EF Core project in 2014. It has not been updated since.

Comment: interesting! Thanks!

Comment: They will bring it back. It's on the roadmap. https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/wiki/Roadmap